# MUI select change the color of the label with SX

Tags: material-ui

I want to change the color of the label when its in its floaty state with sx. Not sure how to do that.

```
<FormControl fullWidth size='small'>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label" sx={{'& Mui-focused':{color:'red'}}}>Bloques Aerial</InputLabel>
     <Select
     labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
     id="demo-simple-select"
     onChange={changeSecondSelect}
     sx={{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}}
     >
         {selectedBlocks?.map((item, index) => {
             return(
                 <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
             )
         })}
     </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.  By inspecting the DOM, the correct CSS selector is `.MuiInputLabel-shrink`.  So your `InputLabel` component would be:

```js
   <InputLabel 
     id="demo-simple-select-label" 
     sx={{
       '&.MuiInputLabel-shrink':{
          color:'red'
        }
     }}
   >
     Bloques Aerial
   </InputLabel>
```